# Element width to match horizontal position of other element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say we have a navigation div which contains elements. Below navigation div there is some bar that must expand to the width where it matches one of the navigation elements (3rd one in this case).

```
<div id="main_navigator">
        <div id="main_navigator_upper">          
            <a id="main_navigator_logo" src="/"></a>
            <ul id="main_navigator_r1">
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 4</a>
                </li>
                <li id="main_navigator_l1">
                    <div id="main_navigator_s1"></div>
                </li>
        <li>
          <ul id="main_navigator_regbox">
            <li>
              <p id="regbox_signin">sign in</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div id="main_navigator_regbox_s1"></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a id="regbox_signup" href="sign_up">sign up</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
                  </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main_navigator_bottom">
            <div id="main_navigator_progression"></div>
              </div>
    </div>
```

From this code, `main_navigator_progression` div must expand its width so it matches `BTN 3`.

You can see the concept [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w5pL8fvw/12/embedded/result/).

---

I've written a simple JS code, but it doesn't seem to be neat and doesn't always work:

```
function initializeProgressorPos() {
    document.getElementById("main_navigator_progression").setAttribute("style", ("width: " + (document.getElementsByClassName("main_nav_btn")[2].getBoundingClientRect().x - document.getElementsByClassName("main_nav_btn")[2].getBoundingClientRect().width) + "px"))
}
initializeProgressorPos();
$(window).resize(function() {
    initializeProgressorPos();
});
```

Is there any way to create such a function that works even when browser is scaled? What could be wrong with my code? Is there any chance that this can be done with pure css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have floatted the element to the right, first you have  to get the width of document, then exclude the width from left of document to the right of element from that amount:

```js
function initializeProgressorPos() {
     var elementRight=$(document).width()- $('.main_nav_btn:eq(2)').offset().left - $('.main_nav_btn:eq(2)').width();
    $("#main_navigator_progression").css({"width": elementRight + "px"});
}
    initializeProgressorPos();

$(window).resize(function() {
    initializeProgressorPos();
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

#main_navigator {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
}
#main_navigator_upper {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
#main_navigator_logo {
 width: 416px;
 height: 120px;
 background-color: white;
}
#main_navigator_r1 {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 padding: 0;
 padding-right: 5%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0px;
 height: 98px;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#main_navigator_r1 li {
 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 /* flex-basis: 0; */
  flex-basis: auto; /* new */
}
#main_navigator_l1 {
 flex-grow: 0.1 !important;
}
#main_navigator_r1 li .main_nav_btn {
 color: white;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: "nexa_bold";
 font-size: 0.9em;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#main_navigator_s1 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 2px;
 height: 35px;
 background-color: #B28039;
}
#main_navigator_regbox {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
#main_navigator_regbox li {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-grow: 0.1;
 flex-shrink: 0.1;
}
#regbox_signin {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #B28039;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-family: "nexa_light";
}
#regbox_signup {
 display: block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-family: "nexa_light";
}
#main_navigator_regbox_s1 {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 1.4px;
 height: 13.5px;
 background-color: white;
}
#main_navigator_bottom {
 background-color: black;
 height: 24px;
}
#main_navigator_progression {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #B28039;
 height: 100%;
 width: 416px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <body>
      <div id="main_navigator">
                <div id="main_navigator_upper">          
                    <a id="main_navigator_logo" src="/"></a>
                    <ul id="main_navigator_r1">
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="main_nav_btn">BTN 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="main_navigator_l1">
                            <div id="main_navigator_s1"></div>
                        </li>
                <li>
                  <ul id="main_navigator_regbox">
                    <li>
                      <p id="regbox_signin">sign in</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div id="main_navigator_regbox_s1"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="regbox_signup" href="sign_up">sign up</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                          </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="main_navigator_bottom">
                    <div id="main_navigator_progression"></div>
             </div>
            </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof of concept.

You can use a combination of a custom `HTML5 data-*` attribute and an `::after` pseudo-element on your navigation menu (and a dash of javascript) to indicate which menu item you have most recently selected.

Despite the dash of javascript, most of the work is done using CSS.

**Working Example:**

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('nav ul');
var menuItems = [... menu.getElementsByTagName('li')];

function selectMenu() {

    menu.dataset.selectedMenu = (menuItems.indexOf(this) + 1);

}

for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {

    menuItems[i].addEventListener('click', selectMenu, false);

}
```

```css
nav ul {
display: flex;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

nav li {
flex: 0 0 60px;
padding: 12px 12px 24px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
list-style-type: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 12px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
transition: width 0.6s linear;
}

nav ul[data-selected-menu="1"]::after {
width: 80px;
}

nav ul[data-selected-menu="2"]::after {
width: 160px;
}

nav ul[data-selected-menu="3"]::after {
width: 240px;
}

nav ul[data-selected-menu="4"]::after {
width: 320px;
}

nav ul[data-selected-menu="5"]::after {
width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul data-selected-menu="1">
<li class="active">Menu 1</li>
<li>Menu 2</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
<li>Menu 5</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hello, can this be done for the containers that have uncertain width?

Comment: Yes. For equal unknown widths, you could use the approach above in very much the same way but use percentages in the CSS instead of `px`. For unequal unknown widths, you could identify the widths with javascript and alter the width of the pseudo-element by updating the CSSOM.